# How to know which are the duplicate entry in MySQL error # 1062?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a column 'cedula' is primary key and I have a 'email' column that is unique key. Executing an INSERT statement type need to know which of the two keys is what is duplicated. Is it possible to know this? And if possible, how to do that?

```
$sentencia = 'INSERT INTO usuario VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';
$sentenciaPreparada = $conexion->prepare($sentencia);

...

$sentenciaPreparada->execute();
$sentenciaPreparada->store_result();

if ($sentenciaPreparada->affected_rows > 0) {
    $sentenciaPreparada->close();
    $this->cerrarConexion();
    return 'REGISTRO_OK';
 } else if ($sentenciaPreparada->errno == 1062) {
     $sentenciaPreparada->close();
     $this->cerrarConexion();

     //In this part the answer would go if the 
     //'cedula' column is duplicated or 'email' column. 
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error message should indicate which column/constraint failed. I recommend *not* exposing this to the user - instead, add additional query checks for anticipated cases such as "duplicate username" or "email already exists".

Comment: When you call $sentenciaPreparada->execute() it should throw an exception with the constraint violation. If that fails, however, you can use $sentenciaPreparada->errorInfo() which returns an array of error info and that should also tell you what is happening.

Comment: How do I do that in code? I know when you get one of the columns is duplicated, but I do not know which to get the two columns is duplicated. And do not show the user, I'm working on an API and just want to make good use of those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cristam try this. I'm posting an answer because I think we will have a language barrier issue with comments.

```
// ADD ERROR CHECKING HERE
if (!$sentenciaPreparada->execute()) {
    var_dump($sentenciaPreparada->error_list);
}

$sentenciaPreparada->store_result();
```

Comment: I got an error with this function: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt :: errorInfo () in C: \ \ wamp \ \ www \ \ WebService \ \ Components \ \ ComponenteAdministrador.php on line 80, referer: http://localhost/webservice / administrador.html 

I'm using mysqli to connect.

Comment: @CristiamMercado Sorry, was reverting myself to PDOStatement, not mysqli_stmt. Try this update

Comment: Jajaja oks @Rottingham no problem. Well, that's better. Now if I can manipulate the information given by the error message. Thank you very much.